# How to export a 16 or 32 bit TIFF file

Tags: export, tiff-format

I have a function that creates a monochrome grayscale image that must be export as a 16-bit and 32-bit TIFF file.  The *Mathematica* documentation mentions that these bit depths are supported during `Export`, but makes no reference as to how to specify them under TIFF or `Export`.

How is the bit depth specified for this type of export?

Comment: `Import[file, "BitDepth"]` gives you the bit depth... so perhaps `Export[file, image, "BitDepth" -> 32]` might do it? Could you try it?

Comment: Possibly some variant maybe, this one produces the error "Not a Valid File Specification"  +1 Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: You might want to look at the 5th example in the documentation for the TIFF format (the one with the Mandrill): http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/TIFF.html.

Comment: sorry chuy -- I was typing my answer in and didn't notice yours till after I posted.

Comment: no problem, rm -rf answered his question 3 hours ago as well :)

Comment: The reason the first example did not work was because you forgot to replace "file" with your own file location. It was not meant to be copied, but understood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Mathematica documentation for .tiff export

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/TIFF.html

there is an example (about the third one down under Basic Examples)

```
 Export["real.tiff", img, "BitDepth" -> 32]
```

where img is the image to export. Seems to work fine.

Comment: The syntax of your solution works very well.  +1 and thanks